# Is it possible to add formatting (such as bold and italics) to the description of a Facebook event page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

I manage the Facebook page for an Orchestra, and the plain text format of the event description makes it difficult to create a readable listing.  I'd like to be able to use bold, italics, bullets, etc., in the description of these Facebook events.   Is there any way to do this (or perhaps even include arbitrary HTML)?

Comment: Still waiting for FB to allow this...

Comment: You can probably add bullets to your event description even if Facebook doesn't support HTML.  If you visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_(typography) then you will see a bullet ( • ) in the first paragraph of the article.  Simply copy and paste the bullet into your event description as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to add formatting to the event description; it does not accept HTML markup.  If you have event details that you want formatted in a certain way, I suggest putting the details on a separate web page and pasting the URL into the event description, or post a link on the event's wall.  It will open in a separate tab when clicked.

Answer (score 4):

Although you cannot add formatting in the traditional sense using HTML markup you can apply some formatting by using unicode character. The easiest way I know to do this is with [yaytext.com](https://yaytext.com/bold-italic/). The following is their description of what you can do:

> YayText Super cool unicode text magic. Write  and/or
>    updates on Facebook, Twitter, and elsewhere. This tool
>   generates bold and italic text using unicode characters (
>   , , ℎ, ... etc.) While the text it
>   generates may look similar to text generated using the HTML  or
>    tags or the CSS attributes font-weight: bold or font-style:
>   italic, it isn't.
>
> You can copy and paste this text into email or use it in your Facebook
>   and Twitter status updates, YouTube comments, etc. Bold and italics
>   are often used to emphasize a point. Bold text can also be used to
>   help structure larger bodies of text, for example, to denote a
>   subject, heading, or title.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, there is, just edit it. Click settings and it should say "description format" and click on it and then it should pop up so you can format it the way you want. It should work because I do it on my iPad all the time.

Comment: @hellokittyliv550 - using the web client, I don't see "description format" as an option anywhere.  Under settings for the event, I have Edit Event, Edit Hosts, Message Guests, Create Repeat Event, Cancel Event, Share, Export, Promote Event.    When editing the event, there are no settings options that I see.     Can you clarify when you see "description format"?

Comment: @TomG:  Maybe it only works on iOS devices.  Or maybe the answerer was just making up lies.

Comment: This is a lie, there has never been a button called this... Don't know why this user whould make that up.

Comment: If an answer is inaccurate or just downright _wrong_, you should _downvote_ it.